# contenteditable div with tailwind adds breaks after child image

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a contenteditable div that contains inline images in between text. With normal css, its works perfectly, however when I apply tailwind, it adds a break after every image. Here is an example:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/YUOFRAZUEn

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add inline class to every one of your images.

e.g.

```
  <img
src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNiIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDE4IDE2IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIj4gPHBhdGggZD0iTTIgMEgxMkwxOCA4TDEyIDE2SDJDMC45IDE2IDAgMTUuMSAwIDE0VjJDMCAwLjkgMC45IDAgMiAwWiIgZmlsbD0icmdiYSgyNTUsIDIwNywgMTA4LCAxKSIvPiA8dGV4dCBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iQXJpYWwsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWYiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTEiIGZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0PSI0MDAiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjciIHk9IjEyIiBmaWxsPSJ3aGl0ZSI+MTwvdGV4dD48L3N2Zz4="
class="1 tagG 0 inline"
```

/>